# PHP : Extracting string between two tags by childs content

Tags: php, html, regex, html-parsing, domdocument

I have this following html markup:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <strong>Online:</strong>
        2/14/2010 3:40 AM
    </li>
    <li>
        <strong>Hearing Impaired:</strong>
        No
        </li>
    <li>
        <strong>Downloads:</strong>
        3,840
    </li>
</ul>
```

and I want to catch `3,840` from last `li` by `"Downloads:"`.

What do you suggest ?

My attempt:

```
preg_match('/<li><strong>Downloads:<\/strong>(.*?)<\/li>/s', $s, $a);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest use an HTML Parser here, `DOMDocument` in particular with xpath.

Example:

```
$markup = '<ul>
    <li>
        <strong>Online:</strong>
        2/14/2010 3:40 AM
    </li>
    <li>
        <strong>Hearing Impaired:</strong>
        No
    </li>
    <li>
        <strong>Downloads:</strong>
        3,840
    </li>
</ul>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($markup);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
// this just simply means get the string next on that strong tag with a text of Downloads:
$download = trim($xpath->evaluate("string(//strong[text()='Downloads:']/following-sibling::text())"));
echo $download; // 3,840
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a html parser for parsing html files. If you insist on regex then you could try the below,

```
<li>[^<>]*<strong>Downloads:<\/strong>\s*\K.*?(?=\s*<\/li>)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/xT4dS2/2)

Code:

```
$string = <<<EOT
<ul>
    <li>
        <strong>Online:</strong>
        2/14/2010 3:40 AM
    </li>
    <li>
        <strong>Hearing Impaired:</strong>
        No
    </li>
    <li>
        <strong>Downloads:</strong>
        3,840
    </li>
</ul>
EOT;
$regex = "~<li>[^<>]*<strong>Downloads:<\/strong>\s*\K.*?(?=\s*<\/li>)~s";
if (preg_match($regex, $string, $m)) {
    $yourmatch = $m[0]; 
    echo $yourmatch;
    } // 3,840
```