# php array from result of mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

what i try to do ?
i try to make code to found if there duplicate data into database or not ,that data it text Content written by users .
so i make sql query to get result of row `pagetext` from database and clean it from any Signs And coordinate (font color, font size, and font type) and image links or any links , and same i do it for Variable `$post['message']` that get Content of text area .. 
than i check if Content  of `$post['message']` is same Content of `pagetext` or not !

Full code :

```
// FUNCTION TO CLEAN TEXT
function stripBBCode($text_to_search)
{
 $pattern = '|[[\/\!]*?[^\[\]]*?]|si';
 $replace = '';
 return preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $text_to_search);
}

// MYSQL QUERY
$ckeck = $db->query_read(" SELECT pagetext FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . " post "); 
$ckeck_num = mysql_num_rows($ckeck); 

            while ($ckeckpagetext = $db->fetch_array($ckeck))
            {

// RESULT FROM QUERY - here i try to make ARRAY BY [square brackets]
$pagetext[] = stripBBCode($ckeckpagetext['pagetext']);
$pagetext[] = preg_replace('/[\s]+/mu','', $pagetext);
$pagetext[] = preg_replace('/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i', '', $pagetext);

// Variable 
$message = stripBBCode($post['message']);
$message = preg_replace('/[\s]+/mu','',$message );
$message = preg_replace('/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i', '', $message);

// LOOP
for($x=0; $x<$ckeck_num; $x++)
{
// CHECK IF THERE duplicate TEXT OR NOT
if ($message == $pagetext[$x])
{
$ckeck_duplicate = 1;
}else{
$ckeck_duplicate = 2;
    }
        }
            }
```

My problem ?
my code Almost correct , but my problem in those lines [square brackets] . when i try great array for my result

```
// RESULT FROM QUERY
$pagetext[] = stripBBCode($ckeckpagetext['pagetext']);
$pagetext[] = preg_replace('/[\s]+/mu','', $pagetext);
$pagetext[] = preg_replace('/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i', '', $pagetext);
```

if i used only first line without used `preg_replace` the code works good .
when i use [square brackets] for a

```
$pagetext[] = stripBBCode($ckeckpagetext['pagetext']);
```

Comment: You might want to look at this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26449506/php-extracting-string-between-two-tags-by-childs-content

Comment: @addicted20015 I'll look at it now thnx

Comment: @addicted20015 , that's not i want .. In fact, far from what I want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $pagetext = array();
    while ($ckeckpagetext = $db->fetch_array($ckeck))    
    {
        $tmpCheckPageText = stripBBCode($ckeckpagetext['pagetext']);
        $tmpCheckPageText = preg_replace('/[\s]+/mu','', $tmpCheckPageText);
        $tmpCheckPageText = preg_replace('/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i', '', $tmpCheckPageText); 
        $pagetext[] = $tmpCheckPageText;
    }
```

And array is:

```
$pagetext = array( 'Plain text1', 'Plain text2' );
```

Comment: thnx but it not work too .. maybe `for()` loop be work ? `for ($i = 0; $i < $ckeck_num; $i++){}` and loop `preg_replace` on it `$pagetext[$i]` and check by `if ($message == $pagetext[$i])` , what do you think ?

Comment: Is works! Show me: `var_dump( $pagetext );` Check this array. If it is what You want You have all u need. Next step is check using `in_array()` function and `$message` variable.

Comment: Yes actually works, I'm sorry .. 
The problem was something else, a Coding, content variable `$post['message']` writes in Arabic, so check not work or do not discover duplicate content . 
i solve the problem using `iconv()` like that `$message = iconv("windows-1256", "UTF-8",$post['message']);` thnx brother

Answer (score 0):

Try Your function **stripBBCode** and **preg_replace** on variable for example **$tmpCheckPageText** and after this put into array **$pagetext**

Code:

```
$tmpCheckPageText = stripBBCode($ckeckpagetext['pagetext']);
$tmpCheckPageText = preg_replace('/[\s]+/mu','', $tmpCheckPageText);
$tmpCheckPageText = preg_replace('/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i', '', $tmpCheckPageText); 
$pagetext[] = $tmpCheckPageText;
```

**UPDATE:**

Create array of pagetext from db using sql statement and *purge it* in while loop. For example you got this:

```
$pagetext = array( 'Purge Text 1', 'Purge Text 2', 'Purge text 3' );
```

After this, purge Your post field **$message**. Next check with **in_array** function.

```
echo in_array( $message, $pagetext ) ? 1 : 2;
```

Comment: okay that is what i want From the beginning, convert the variable `$pagetext` to `array` and use `in_array` ... but how i do this Create array from sql query `$pagetext = array( 'Purge Text 1', 'Purge Text 2', 'Purge text 3' );`

Comment: and if i Create result on array , can i use it with `preg_replace`